# how to run python in eclipse with both py2 and py3?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

pre:

1. I installed both python2.7 and python 3.70
2. eclipse installed pydev, and configured two interpreters for each py version
3. I have a project with some py scripts

question:

I choose one py file, I want run it in py2, then i want it run in py3(manually).

I know that each file cound has it's run configuration, but it could only choose one interpreter a time.

I also know that py.exe could help you get the right version of python.

I tried to add an interpreter with py.exe, but pydev keeps telling me that "python stdlibs" is necessary for a interpreter while only python3's lib shows up.

so, is there a way just like right click the file and choose "run use interpreter xxx"?
or, does pydev has the ability to choose interpreters by "#! python2"/"#! python3" at file head?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what's the actual workflow you want...

Do you want to run each file on a different interpreter (say you have `mod1.py` and want to run it always on `py2` and then `mod2.py` should be run always on `py3`) or do you want to run the same file on multiple interpreters (i.e.: you have `mod1.py` and want to run it both on `py2` and `py3`) or something else?

So, please give more information on what's your actual problem and what you want to achieve...

---

Options to run a single file in multiple interpreters:

1. Always run with the default interpreter (so, make a regular run -- `F9` to run the current editor -- change the default interpreter -- using `Ctrl+shift+Alt+I` -- and then rerun with `Ctrl+F11`).
2. Create a `.sh`/`.bat` which will always do 2 launches (initially configure it to just be a wrapper to launch with one python, then, after properly configuring it inside of PyDev that way change it to launch python 2 times, one with py2 and another with py3 -- note that I haven't tested, but it should work in theory).

Comment: what I want is, run one file like mod1.py, in multiple interpreters.

Comment: Ok, added more info to the answer for that workflow.